# Catch a Checkbox 'CheckedChanged' event when using ColorBox for Confirmation

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox, colorbox

I have an ASP.Net Form page, using C#, with a check box inside a Gridview.  I'm trying to get ColorBox to behave as a confirmation box. I can get it to work fine when used on a link, but it will not stop the event from passing through to the check boxes CheckChanged event handler in the code behind.

Any suggestions on stopping the propagation of the event? I've tried Bind and Live and it still passes through.

jQuery Code:

```
$(".approver").change(function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                var dialog = '<div">'
                + '<div id="dialog">'
                + '<p style="margin-top: 30px;">'
                + 'Are you sure you want to approve this program?</p>'
                + '<p style="font-size: small;">'
                + '<strong>Note:</strong> This cannot be undone!</p>'
                + '<p style="text-align: center;">'
                + '<a href="#" onclick="' + this.href + '", CloseBox();" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Reset</a>'
                + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                + '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;" class="btn btn-small">Cancel</a>'
                + '</p></div></div>';

                $.colorbox(
                {
                    href: dialog,
                    open: true,
                    title: "Program Approval",
                    inline: true,
                    height: '230px'
                });
                return false;
        });
```

The Checkbox in GridView:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkApproved" 
runat="server" 
CssClass="approver" 
Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved")) %>'
OnCheckedChanged="chkApproved_CheckedChanged" 
AutoPostBack="True"
Enabled='<%# !Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved")) %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, but only after fixing a IE error ... Thanks to [Jack Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409473/jack).

[Colorbox and inline html not showing in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808652/colorbox-and-inline-html-not-showing-in-ie8)